# Create list in one thread

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list

If I create a linked lists inside one thread, can other threads see these lists? I saved the head of each list in one dimensional pointers array and this array is global.

Comment: Yes, provided the accesses to the global array of pointers are synchronized properly.

Comment: Yes, it's synchronized properly using mutex

Comment: In that case, changes to the global array made in one thread will be visible in another. However, since you're using a linked list, remember to also protect accesses to the nodes themselves if they are modified after being published to the global array.

Comment: I don't need to modify them after being published to the global array. Just read